# Are PCC and Collin's reagent completely identical in their oxidizing action?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, organic-oxidation

Are PCC and Collin's reagent completely identical in their oxidizing action? Is there any advantage (or disadvantages) over the other?

Answer (score 3):

In the [Wikipedia article of PCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyridinium_chlorochromate), it is written that:

> PCC offers the advantage of the selective oxidation of alcohols to aldehydes or ketones, whereas many other reagents are less selective.

Further, on the [Wikipedia article of Collin's reagent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collins_reagent), it is written that:

> This complex is both difficult and dangerous to prepare, as it is very hygroscopic and can inflame during preparation. It is typically used in a sixfold excess in order to complete the reaction. Nowadays, PCC or PDC oxidation have largely supplanted Collins oxidation for these reasons.

Comment: Okay, so PCC wins in preparation part.